# loading static javascript file in nuxt with pug

Tags: javascript, static, pug, nuxt.js

In this page https://liceupsicologic.org/es-co/dialogo I have a subscribe button ("Suscribirse"). It calls a method from a static JS file. So I have that js file in the Nuxt static folder: https://liceupsicologic.org/mailer.js. I'm also using pug. The code looks like this:

```
button(onclick="ml_account('webforms', '2085164', 'k8s3x9', 'show')").btn.btn-dialogo.susc {{ botonSus[$store.state.lang] }}

script(src="/mailer.js")
```

When I run "npm run dev", it works fine. If I inspect the code, I find what I expect in the DOM:

```
<script src="/mailer.js" data-v-1cfbc23f>
```

But when I deploy the app, that script tag is not there and the button is not working. Why? What am I doing wrong?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to achieve what I wanted, but I still think the question needs an answer. Why the my code was working on the development environment but was broken on production?

Anyway, What I did was to delete this line from the template:

```
script(src="/mailer.js")
```

And add this piece of code in the script of the component:

```
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: '/mailer.js' }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```